# How do I create an animated number counter using Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, alpine.js

I want to create a animated number counter using alpine js something exactly like this if there is a plugins or something can help me please told me.

**Code :**

```
<div id="counter">Counter: <b counter="0">0</b></div>

function update_users_count() {
    $('#counter b').animate({
        counter: 25000
    }, {
        duration: 6000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        },
        complete: update_users_count
    });
};
update_users_count();
```

**Alpine.JS**

> Error code is : Uncaught ReferenceError: counterA is not defined

```
<script>
function counterExample() {
    return {
        counterA: 0,
        target: '+100',
        time: 2000,
        init() {
            const start = counterA;
            const steps = time / (target - start);
            const handle = setInterval(() => {
                if (counterA < target) {
                    counterA += Math.round((target - start) / steps);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(handle);
                    counterA = target;
                }
            }, time / steps);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Example of what I want to do :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script><html>
<body>
    <div x-data="{ current: 0, target: 1000, time: 300}" x-init="() => {
        start = current; 
        const interval = Math.max(time / (target - start), 5); 
        const step = (target - start) /  (time / interval);  
        const handle = setInterval(() => {
            if(current < target) 
                current += step
            else {
                clearInterval(handle);
                current = target
            }   
            }, interval)
    }">
             <div class="card"x-text="Math.round(current)">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is a simple problem in **target**option when I change it to for example **1000** it's been so slow

Comment: @jhon-jhonesi made some fine tuning. and i tested it.  but you should figure out it by yourself.

Comment: I custom the code but it's not working `<script>
  function counterExample() {
    return {
  counterA: 0, 
  target: '100', 
  time: 2000,
  init() {
   start = counterA; 
   const steps = time / (target - start);
   const handle = setInterval(() => {
    if(counterA < target) {
     counterA += Math.round((target - start) / steps);
    } else {
     clearInterval(handle);
     counterA = target;
    }
   }, time/steps);
  }
 }
  }
</script>`

Comment: target : '100' you pass string.... and whole your comment with this formatting ....

Comment: I can recommend using the Alpine JS Intersect-plugin, so the count only starts if the div is in the viewport. Otherwise, it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using Alpine.js [Intersect plugin](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/intersect) and `requestAnimationFrame`. Sharing for anyone else that might come across this question!

```html
<div x-data="{ visible: false, start: 0, target: 1000, duration: 3000 }"
    x-intersect:enter.full="visible = true" x-intersect:leave="visible = false; start = 0"
    x-init="$watch('visible', value => {
        const $el = $refs.el;
        const step = (timestamp) => {
            if (!start) start = timestamp;
            const progress = timestamp - start;
            const percentage = Math.min(progress / duration, 1);
            const value = Math.floor(percentage * target);
            $el.innerHTML = value.toLocaleString();
            if (progress < duration) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            }
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    })">
    <span x-ref="el">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this was very helpful as it also takes into account the user scrolling into the viewport.